# Google search results mobile adding ?m=1 to end of site address

Tags: google-search

I recently helped a friend migrate from Blogger to Wordpress.  Everything is working great, and everything seems to be propagated.  Google search results are already displaying the new site information, but I've run into a small problem.

When I search for her site on google from my desktop, results are fine.  However, when I search on a mobile device, the search results appear to be okay but when you actually click the link it adds ?m=1 to the end of the site address, causing the link not to work.

I think ?m=1 was a Blogger thing - so I'm not sure why it is still doing this when nameservers are updated, and Google obviously reindexed the site.

My question is this - is there something I can do to prevent this from being added to the end of the site address for Google search results?  Or do we just have to wait for Google indexing/crawling to take care of that?

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is create a redirection either through a webserver configuration file (such as adding rewriterules with a R=301 flag in apache's .htaccess) or modify the section(s) of your script that is handling the m=1 parameter so that it redirects to the valid site without the m=1.

When you are done the changes, update at least the sitemaps containing the affected URL's and re-upload them to your google webmaster tools account so google knows to try to index the new pages.

To do it the script way, add this in PHP:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Redirect",true);
header("Location: http://example.com/path/to/mobile/page",true);
```

But of course, change the actual location to reflect the real page without the m parameter.

Let me know your progress and I can update you with a better answer if needed.

Comment: Thanks Mike - I am actually pretty new at this, and I'm a little hesitant to update the .htaccess file.... and since I'm using WordPress, I'm not too sure what script would be handling the m=1 parameter.  It seems like it is something Google is appending to the end of the address - as nothing in Wordpress is actually adding ?m=1 to the end.

Comment: You'll have to look at a PHP script in the wordpress distribution. Start with index.php and add `$_GET['m'];exit();` in the line right after `<?php` at the very top. then when you run that file, you should see a 1 on a blank screen to confirm M is 1. now change your URL so that it ends with `m=2`. Now when you run the script, you should see only a 2 on the screen. Now remove `$_GET['m'];exit();` from the file so that wordpress runs normally. Once you identified where m=1 is being picked up, you can make a redirect script at that point depending on what needs redirected etc.